# Can Lex and Yacc lex and parse themselves?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

Can Lex and Yacc, together, lex and parse both Lex and Yacc?

In other words, is it possible to write a Lex/Yacc combination that is self hosting, generating their own parsers?

EDIT: I do not mean that the combination needs to parse the C parts of the input fully. In particular, it does not need to deal with the typedef-name/identifier conflict, or build a full symbol table (though I *believe* that both can be dealt with with C code in the lexer and parser). This is because the C code is copied verbatim to the output.

EDIT 2: Basically, do Lex and Yacc (the languages, not the programs) have LALR(1) grammers?

Comment: Lex and Yacc are both code generators, so can't do anything purely by themselves -- you need a compiler to compile the output into a useable program.  If you include a C compiler, the answer is trivially yes, as they are written in C.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I mean using Lex and Yacc to generate the C code used to parse themselves

Comment: What do you mean by 'parse themselves'?  Lex are yacc are programs (executables) you run, you don't parse them.  If you mean "Use them to write a parser that parses the input language of lex or yacc", the answer is again trivially yes, as long as you have a C compiler to compile the output.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I meant the latter (and it is a non-trivial question -- Lex and Yacc cannot easily parse C++ for example).

Comment: I don't see what C++ has to do with it. The lex and yacc metalanguages are very simple and easily processed by their own processors. For example  the lex metalanguage doesn't need parsing at all, only scanning. The yacc metalanguage would only be a few dozen lines if specified in itself.

Comment: @EJP I just meant that there are some grammers that Yacc cannot parse (without ugly hacks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the answer is actually more complex than what the first answers reported.  I claim that, no, YACC cannot parse YACC, but evil is in the details.

The natural grammar for YACC includes:

```
gram: %empty | gram rule
rule: ID ":" rhs
rhs: %empty | rhs ID
```

(using Bison-like conventions: `":"` is a valueless token, `ID` is the token for identifiers, and `%empty` emphasizes rules with an empty RHS).

It's not hard to see that this grammar is not LR(1).  Being LR(1) roughly means that when your cursor advances, you know in which rule you are just by looking at the next token.  Then consider the following (valid) input:

```
ID : ID ID
ID : ID
ID :
```

can you spot easily when starts a rule and when begins the next one?  Well, too easy this way, try to find out as YACC would see it:

```
ID : ID ID ID : ID ID :
```

How do you know when the first rule is finished?  Consider the position of the cursor as a `.` below:

```
ID : ID . ID ID : ID ID :
```

Is the first rule finished?  Of course not.  And what about the next step?

```
ID : ID ID . ID : ID ID :
```

Is the first rule finished?  Yes obviously.  But in both case the next token (aka the "lookahead") is `ID`; it is the following token which helps deciding whether the current rule is finished (when `":"`) or not (`ID`).  In other words 1 lookahead is not enough, this grammar is not LR(1), and therefore not LALR(1) either (which is the class of grammars that YACC accepts).  Clearly it is LR(2).

It would be extremely easy to make this grammar LR(1) had we accepted to change the language and require a terminating `;` for rules:

```
ID : ID ID ; ID : ID ; ID : ;
```

unfortunately it's too late and POSIX did not decide to make this semicolon mandatory, so implementations of YACC must deal with this LR(2) grammar.

In the case of Bison, it uses a neat/dirty (depends on your viewpoint) trick to deal with it: the *scanner* is taught to make the difference between a "regular" identifier (ID) and an identifier followed by a colon (ID_COLON).  Then the flow of tokens reads

```
ID_COLON ID ID ID_COLON ID ID_COLON
```

and this is obviously LR(1).

So why wasn't the semicolon required from the inception of YACC?  Well, for obvious bootstrapping reasons YACC cannot be written first in YACC, so I guess S. Johnson never realized that the parser he wrote by hand actually accepted a grammar which is harder than LR(1).  Bison and byacc come from a common clone whose parser was also written by hand.  Bison's own parser was bootstrapped much later, in 2002 ([commit e9955c83734d0a545d7822a1feb9c4a8038a62cb](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git/commit/?id=e9955c83734d0a545d7822a1feb9c4a8038a62cb)).

Much of what I have written can be debated depending on how you see things.  I claim the "natural" grammar is not LR(1), but I don't think one may define "natural" here.  So yes, others may say that the grammar of YACC is LR(1).  But in the end, we are all right, since if a language is LR(k), then it is LR(1) (i.e., an LR(k) grammar can be turned into a LR(1) monster grammar, which is proved using a similar dirty/neat trick).

Wrt Flex, well, yes, it is bootstrapped, but it's also somewhat untrue to say so: it overall syntax is really simple and easily described by regexps.  However the regexps themselves escape the realm of mere regular languages: there are parentheses!  So somewhere inside Lex/Flex, there must be a real parser, be it generated or hand written, to parse the regexps.

Asking if Lex is bootstrapped is similar to asking whether the C preprocessor is bootstrapped: yes it is, I'm sure there are `#include`s in there :)

Comment: I meant can Lex and Yacc (together) parse both Lex and Yacc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and they do. The *flex* implementation of lex is bootstrapped. <strike>Ditto *yacc* if I remember correctly.</strike>

> EDIT 2: Basically, do Lex and Yacc (the languages, not the programs) have LALR(1) grammars?

That's not the same question. <strike>*yacc* has an LALR(1) grammar.</strike> *lex* could well have an LALR(1) grammar, but that doesn't mean that *lex* uses/can use a generated parser. But it can scan its own .l files.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX specification for [`yacc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/yacc.html) includes a Yacc grammar for recognizing the input to Yacc.  Therefore yes, the Yacc grammar can be written in Yacc.

The POSIX specification for [`lex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/lex.html) does not include a Lex specification for the regular expressions it recognizes.  However, that does not mean that such a specification cannot be produced.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given above is the essence of the matter. There is no mandatory semi-colon at the ends of rules, so an extra look-ahead is required to determine whether an identifier is followed by a colon. If so, then this indicates the left-hand side of a new rule.

It may, in fact, be possible to parse yacc **even with** this issue, without having to hack yacc grammar like bison did - by just simply not using yacc at all, but using only lex!

The grammar specified by POSIX is actually a *regular* grammar that specifies a finite state transducer. The transducer is deterministic, precisely because the identifier-colon ambiguity can be resolved. Therefore, if you set up the right kind of finite state machine in lex making use of lex's start condition facility in the right way, then you should be able to parse a yacc grammar with lex ... and to bootstrap an implementation of yacc with just lex.